# Feeling palloff press more in arms than core

Tags: abdominals

I've been trying to train my obliques using the anti ab rotation exercise called the pallof press. Here is a picture:

[image]

You can bring the band to your sternum and then again push put while keeping elbows near to the chest.

For some reason I feel this exercise more in my shoulders than my obliques. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your deltoid and traps are relatively weaker than your core, you have not braced your core before starting, or you have your scapula overly protracted.

If it is an over protracted scapula you are pushing the tension further away from your body, which would make it feel more like a shoulder exercise.

Comment: What are some cues to fix the overprotracted scapula thingy?

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom pinch your shoulder blades together behind you.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, try doing the press in a tall kneeling position so you can focus more on what the core is doing.

[image]

A few coaching cues that might help:

- Drive the knees into the ground
- Powerful exhale through pursed lips with each press

If you're still feeling it in your shoulder, reduce the weight/tension in the band.

Hope that helps.